# How to handle comparison operator for Generic Java class accepting String or Integer

Tags: java, generics, compare, comparator

I am interested in using a generic Java class which can handle `String` or `Integer` data type. I'd like to utilize the comparison operator, but it appears to have a compile error:

> Operator < cannot be used on generic `T`

How can I achieve using comparison operators such as <, >, =, etc. for `T`? (Assuming `T` is `Number` or `String`).

```
public class Node<T>    {
        public T value;

        public Node(){
        }

        public void testCompare(T anotherValue) {
            if(value == anotherValue)
                System.out.println("equal");
            else if(value < anotherValue)
                System.out.println("less");
            else if(value > anotherValue)
                System.out.println("greater");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't. You can only compare primitive numeric types. Boxed primitive numeric types will be automatically unboxed, so that works too. For all other types: not possible to use the comparison operator.

Comment: How do you want to compare an Integer to a String? Sounds like this design is not properly thought through. Take a step back and explain why you need this.

Comment: @Thilo  I was wondering if it's possible for this Node to take either type Integer or type String and  if it is one or the other,   be able to compare between 2 integers or compare between 2 strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface:

```
public class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    public T value;

    public Node() {
    }

    public void testCompare(T anotherValue) {
        int cmp = value.compareTo(anotherValue);
        if (cmp == 0)
            System.out.println("equal");
        else if (cmp < 0)
            System.out.println("less");
        else if (cmp > 0)
            System.out.println("greater");
    }
}
```

It's implemented by `String`, `Integer`, `Long`, `Double`, `Date` and many other classes.

Comment: Thank you Tagir, this is the solution I was looking for!

Comment: And if T is a custom class (non-primitive), it will require it to implement Comparable. Great!

Comment: Nice and clever solution.