# getMax() operater "<" cannot be applied to <T>

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I am very new to linked lists and nodes so I am completely stuck on my getMax() method in Java.

So I am trying to get the largest value in the list but I can't use "<" in my if statment, what am I supposed to use instead? Do I need to do compareTo? But then I don't know what I would be comparing.

This is the code I have so far:

```
public T getMax()
    {
        T largestValue = null;
        Node<T> currNode = this.firstNode;
        while (currNode.next != null)
        {
            if(largestValue < currNode.next.data)


        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set constraints on generic types in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081663/how-to-set-constraints-on-generic-types-in-java)

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica No, it won't. The OP needs `compareTo`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle comparison operator for Generic Java class accepting String or Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32086894/how-to-handle-comparison-operator-for-generic-java-class-accepting-string-or-int)

Answer (score 4):

You (presumably; your snippet is too short) have no bounds on T, so T could be anything. Notably, it could be, say, `InputStream`, which is not inherently comparable. Therefore, it is **not possible** to apply any sort of "is this particular instance of T 'below' this other instance of T" operation on this, as there is no guarantee this operation even makes sense.

You need to make that make sense.

In java, that'll be the job of `Comparable`, **or**, you separate out the notion of 'the kind of thing I operate on' and 'code that can determine, given 2 things, which one is lower'.

The former means you want T to be bound. You also messed up your handling of `next`. I'll fix both.

```
public class MyClassThingie<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    public T getMax() {
        T largestValue = null;
        Node<T> currNode = this.firstNode;
        while (currNode != null) {
            if (largestValue == null || largestValue.compareTo(currNode.data) < 0) largestValue = currNode.data;
            currNode = currNode.next;
        }
        return largestValue;
        // you may want to spec out that your method returns null if there are 0 elements.
    }
}
```

If you want the other model, have a constructor that accepts a `Comparator<T>`; see the source of e.g. `TreeSet` for some examples.

Note that `T extends Comparable<T>` means: T is some type for which the following holds: It implements `Comparable<T>`. In other words, it is a thing that is capable of comparing itself to other things of its own kind. `String` is such a type. So is `Integer`. (Integer implements `Comparable<Integer>`; String implements `Comparable<String>`).

Comment: Small note: For maximum flexibility it should be `T extends Comparable<? super T>`.

Comment: thank you this is exactly what I needed, makes so much more sense!